# Subversion - How do I commit? I updated one of my project directories to a previous revision

Tags: version-control

First, I used "update to revision" to update one of my directories to an old revision because we had to undo some changes.

However, when I go to commit now, It is stating that items of my project are out of date and that I should try updating.

However, I really don't want my current files to be replaced by any "newer" files in the revision.

I would like this commit to jump ahead and be the head revision.

Any tips?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you want to do is called a "reverse merge".  Update your working copy to head, then perform a reverse merge to the revision you desire.  There is a section in the SVN book about it [here](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/ch04s04.html), under the "Undoing Changes" section.

For example, if you are at revision 412, but you want to back up to the contents of revision 410, use something like the following:

```
svn merge -r 412:410 http://yourrepository/trunk
```

This will get your working copy to reflect the state at 410, and then you can do a commit.

Comment: Thanks for the info! Now I know how to undo changes. Any idea how to get out of my current situation? (That resulted from me doing an "update to revision") I've since put in quite a few hours on the project in this "reverted" state.

Comment: Try `svn diff > changes.diff` into a file, then update, reverse merge, and `patch -p 0 -i changes.diff`

Comment: Thanks for the information Anton. I'm sure that would have worked fine... however, I have zero experience with direct subversion commands. I did figure out a rather tedious solution to my problem. Using Tortoise SVN, I went ahead and updated the entire directory in question resulting in many files being in conflict. I went to "Edit Conflicts" On each file and told it to use "Mine" in each case. I then right clicked each file and marked them as resolved. Then, I committed each file. It's not the most elegant solution but it got the job done for me. Thanks for all of the help!